# using spread operator in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-next

I want to write a function which returns me a component wrapped up in another. The function I'm trying to write is like below in JavaScript.

```
function GetGroup({ name, text, isRequired, ...props })
```

Here, `name`, `text`, and `isRequired` is obtained from the passed arguments and others are sent to another component as `props`.

How to write it in TypeScript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So firstly, Object Rest/Spread is a proposed ECMAScript feature that is well on its way to being standardized, having reached Stage 4, [and is in the process of being formally adopted](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/1048).

As you know from its usage, it makes working with plain JavaScript objects, incredibly flexible.

Information about the typing of the feature is available in the [TypeScript 2.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html) documentation. As it very eloquently states:

> Object rests are the dual of object spreads, in that they can extract any extra properties that don’t get picked up when destructuring an element:

And indeed there are actually two features in play, the one complementing the other.

**Object Rest**

When the *Rest* portion of the feature is used, it enhances object destructuring by enabling us to collect the rest of the properties into a new object comprised of them.

We can write the type annotation as we would for any other value. For example

```
interface GroupProperties {
  name: string;
  text: string;
  isRequired?: boolean;
  values: string[];
  flagged: boolean;
}

function Group({ name, text, isRequired, ...rest }: GroupProperties) {
  console.log(rest);
}
```

This informs the type system that `name` and `text` are of type `string` and that `is required` is of type `boolean`.
Further the type system then knows that `rest` has two properties, `values` and `flagged` of types `boolean` and `string` respectively. The type of `rest` is deduced.

**Object Spread**

When the *Spread* portion of the feature is used it enhances object construction by enabling declarative construction of an object from multiple sources, effortless creating derivatives, as well as easy undefining and overriding.

The type system also understands the meaning of Spread expressions and infers the types they evaluate to.

```
const o = {x: 1, y: 'hello'};

const o1 = {
  ...o,
  y: 1
};
```

In the above, o1 has type `{x: number, y: number}`.

Comment: You can also write the type in the function definition: `function Group({ name, text, ...}: {name: string, text: string, ...})`

Comment: @BallpointBen, indeed, but I find it quickly becomes unreadable as the number of properties exceeds three

Answer (score 2):

```
function GetGroup({ name, text, isRequired, ...props }: { name: string; text: string; isRequired: boolean; other: number; arg: string }) {
  props.other // number
  props.arg // string
}
```

TypeScript is just about adding types.. and `name`, `text` and `isRequired` are normal arguments. `props`, on the other hand, are the rest of the arguments. So, whatever the remaining arguments, are assumed to be the rest of the declared types.

Comment: Added little more info, @aloisdg

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Aluan's answer, you can also use this [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) syntax (seen here as `[propName]`) to add on a dynamic number of `any` type properties to an object type or interface:

```
const getGroup = 
  ({ name, text, isRequired, ...props }:
  { name: string; text: string; isRequired: boolean; [propName: string]: any;}) =>
    console.log(name, text, isRequired, props);
    
  getGroup({'a': 1, 'b': 2, name: 's', text: 'o', isRequired: false});
```

result:

```
[LOG]: "s",  "o",  false,  {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 2
    }
```

[code playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygcQE4gK4AcYF4YBQMMAFAN4xgCGAtggDQxQIAeUjAlhAEoICOGDqgQATRgDpJWdFggwAvgC4YFanWXRUHMHADcTVlA1QtO-V14Cho5QCMQIADYIqYfQG1pILADlaCY1M4AF1lVwBPXXkASjwAPhhQSCcEcUcQOBIvWWjdAgJEFHRscgByKlLlAEZGUttKmAAmRjUAmFKIUsZmNmVSkC6YC35BYRFlADMqRwgEGN0gA)